# Path of the local directory

Tags: c#

A rather simple question; how to find the path of the local directory in which my exe is placed? As-in I have an .exe and in the program I have to create a txt file in the directory where the exe is!

[language - C#]

So, if the exe is in C:/Temp  and is started from there; my txt should be created in C:/Temp

If the user wishes to move the exe to D:/Temp and runs from there; I should be able to create the txt file in D:/Temp

I tried the Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() but that returns the directory of the execution of the program!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location`

Comment: The "Assembly" Class is part of the System.Reflection namespace - for those who would be looking for that...

Answer (score 13):

try this

```
sPath = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
```

or else

```
sAppPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
```

Answer (score 2):

A similar information is in [`System.Appdomain.BaseDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.basedirectory%28v=VS.90%29.aspx), the base directory that the assembly resolver uses to probe for assemblies.
In simple cases, this will point to the location of the original `.exe` assembly.

```
String path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
this.GetType().Assembly.CodeBase
```

or if it's a WinForms app

```
Application.ExecutablePath
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Application.StartupPath**. It Gets the path for the executable file that started the application, not including the executable name.

Comment: When running from the debugger in VS 2010 that resolves to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE".