# How can I reference the file (json) after the application installed (click once)

Tags: c#, clickonce

I have a JSON file added to the project, set to "Copy if newer". I know that i can reach it in Debug if i write the path, but i can't figure it out how to reach it after the successfull installation. Should i refer to the added JSON file, or just give the future path? I never published anything before so i could use some help.

```
System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", Environment.CurrentDirectory + "//SzakD-8a80930e8c75.json");
```

Comment: you need get the "right" path of where your app is sitting when deployed because it is different from what it is when you are debugging locally. you need to "find it out" so that your program knows where to look for your file. check this answer for more info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911204/path-of-the-local-directory

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Assembly assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", assembly.Location + "//SzakD-8a80930e8c75.json");
```